# Swapping images using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I just started reading about JavaScript. As a language, I don't have any trouble with it, but I came across an annoying situation.

I was going to try my first JavaScript function for a simple action: changing the src attribute of an `<img>`.

So let's imagine I have this code in index.html:

```js
function activate(id) {
  document.images(id).src = "home-on.jpg";
}

function deactivate(id) {
  document.images(id).src = "home-off.jpg";
}
```

```html
<img id="home" src="home-off.jpg" onmouseover="activate('home')" onmouseout="deactivate('home')"/>
```

The code works perfectly on Google Chrome (swapping the image when the mouse is over, and out), but I have no luck with Firefox.

Any help?

Comment: advice: use css to perform this function :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the wrong syntax to get the images.

You need to write `document.images[id]` (With brackets `[]`, not parentheses `()`)

The `document.images` collection is an associative array, which is indexed using brackets.
Parentheses are used to invoke a function; I don't know why your code worked in Chrome.

Comment: Yes, and he can also consider just using document.getElementById(id) as well.

Comment: Well thank you. I wasn't aware that document.iamges was an array, I actually thought it was a function! . And yes, I'm a programmer so I know how functions are usually invoked.

Comment: You'd be surprised by the average level of some of the beginners here.  Also, had you been coming from VB, the distinction would have been new to you.

Comment: Why? is the average level too slow or too high?

Comment: For some people, far too low.

Answer (score 1):

SLaks has entered the correct answer for this particular question.

However, you will find in JavaScript that there is a lot of cases like this where incorrect syntax will work in one browser but not in the next. For ensuring that you maintain cross browser compatibility in JavaScript you might find a library such as jQuery very handy.  Not only does it attempt to ensure that your JavaScript code is compatible with all browsers, it also extends a lot of great functionality.

Comment: Than you, I was already thinking in using jQuery, but I wanted to start from the ground before getting into frameworks. :-)